# Error Installing IJulia - Unknown Package

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I installed the Anaconda package and then tried to install the IJulia package and I get:

[image]

As you can see Update didnt work either, which was the only possible instruction I could find upon a quick search...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong in your Julia installation.

The easiest thing to do (although a bit drastic) is probably to delete the `.julia` directory in your home directory and try again. The installed packages are stored in that directory, so deleting it will "reinitialise" the package manager.

Note also that it is no longer necessary to separately install Anaconda in order to use `IJulia` -- if it does not find a Jupyter installation, it will install the required packages itself.

Comment: It might be sufficient to just delete the `.julia/v0.4/METADATA` folder.